# Tricky sticky footer with sidebar

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to place a sticky footer inside of the content area of a page with a full-height sidebar.

Here is a copy of the page I'm working on:
http://www.lavenderstone.co.uk/stackoverflow/

[image]

I've worked with http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ many times successfully in the past, and a method using %'s instead. The twist to the problem I'm having is there is a 100% height sidebar (green) and I need the footer (orange) at the bottom of the content div (grey).

I can't place the footer div at the bottom of its parent div, nor can I force its sibling to have 100% height minus the hight of the footer. I've tried both to no avail.

I could place the footer right at the bottom of the page, but this would disrupt the design of the side bar. Can anyone help? I'm almost wanting to resort to javascript!

Answer (score 0):

add this style to content-wrap element

```
#content-wrap{
    height:100%;
}
```

put your footer element in your content element and add this style;

```
#footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```